# How can i change the background color and font color for a particular condition for multiple columns at a time in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix, ssrs-grouping, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a Tablix which has around 50 columns,I need to change the color of the font, if the value in the columns are less than 0.Is it possible to write the expression at one time rather than writing the expression for every column individually?

Answer (score 2):

Without using the code section, the best you can do is to embed the logic in a hidden parameter, then refer to that parameter value for color in each of the columns.  That way you can change the logic/color in one place.